# PostgreSQL regex_replace substitution for 2 groups

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-replace

I have column in Postgres db which has text in `char varying` data type. The text includes an uri which contains file name and resembles as below;

```
  The file is a file of \\88-77-99-666.abc.example.com\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\20221122\12345678.PDF [9bc8rer55c655f4cb5df763c61862d3fdde9557b0] is the sha1 of the file.
```

I am trying to get the file name `12345678.PDF` and date `20221122`  from the text content. However, regexp_replace either gives me everything till file name or everything after filename. I am trying to get only file name

```
1>> Regexp_replace(data, '.+\\', '')
```

Yields filename and everything after it

```
 2>> Regexp_replace(data, '\[.*', '')
```

Yields filename and everything after it

If I capture two groups like below I get same result as 1.

```
Regexp_replace(data, '.+\\|\[', '')
```

How can I substitute 2 groups and only get filename? Or what is the better way to achieve this? And I need to get the date value but if I can figure this out maybe I will be able to apply the learning for to extract date value. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're running a replace function, so you'll need to capture the part that you want to keep and replace the rest of the string with it. Try something like ```Regexp_replace(data, '.+\\(.+)`.*', '\1')```

Comment: I tried it but I getting the full string back. I tried this `substring(data from '\w*.PDF')` which returns the desired results but if the extension is not PDF then I am not getting the result. I could use `\w*\.[aA-zZ] but the string has domain as `example.vpc.com` resulting in undesired result. Trying to figure out how to further qualify the substring to get extensions such as Pdf, pdf, DOC, doc and its likes

Comment: Maybe ``REGEXP_MATCHES(col, "`([^`]+)` *\[([^][]+)")``?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your suggestion and getting null results

Comment: @Alsheik It [works here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DvfzeQCR).

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work; I have scrubbed the original content for your test; I tried it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wV0relDd) with 0 results, additionally updating the question with actual text content as an aside, only looking for filename from the URI. Thanks for looking into this
`SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('The file is a file of \\88-77-99-666.abc.example.com\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\20221122\2779780.PDF [9bc8rer55c655f4cb5df763c61862d3fdde9557b0] is the sha1 of the file.',
  '`([^`]+)` *\[([^\]\[]+)') AS Result;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew pardon my ignorance what is the purpose of backtick ` \` ` character in your expression?

Comment: @Alsheik Your string - that you edited an hour ago - contained the backticks. If you have a char in your string, it can be matched.

Comment: Apologies, formatting error my end, did not realize the backtick existed in my original post. I made the change and I was getting only `{The}` which is the first word in the test content. Check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/79OaOjx-). I'm definitely missing something

Comment: Maybe `'(\S+)\s+\[([^][]+)'`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not yield the desired result of grabbing only the `filename.pdf`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(
  'The file is a file of \\88-77-99-666.abc.example.com\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\20221122\2779780.PDF [9bc8rer55c655f4cb5df763c61862d3fdde9557b0] is the sha1 of the file.',
  '([^[:space:]\\/]+)\s+\[([^][]+)') AS Result;
```

See the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ChrhbAp4), result:

[image]

*Details*:

- `([^[:space:]\\/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `\`, `/` and whitespace
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `[` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, your answer got me what I wanted with slight change `([^[:space:]\\/]+)\s+\[`  as it gets the required filename.pdf portion and I decided to go with `substring` vs `regex_matches` to avoid the curly braces, [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql12/a508b45a48204991ec2ea61083292d22/). Again thanks for the help. Now on to figuring out how to extract the `date folder` before `\filename.pdf`will update the thread once I find the answer.

Comment: To find the date folder, '`\\([0-9]{8})\\`' gives me the desired results as its in  YYYYMMDD. [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql12/1e5a216991b0b5eff611d67c042b5d85/). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Unable to get the 2xbackslashes in my previous comment, refer to SQLize link for answer